# How Can I Detect App Termination of React Native App (esp Android)?

Tags: react-native

How can I detect termination of a react native app so I can do some cleanup? Currently I only care about this for Android.

Comment: Is the cleanup code you are trying to run on the JS side? I've found its easier and more reliable to run cleanup on app start. I've tried triggering some logic when the app terminates, using the ReactActivity's lifecycle event`onHostDestroy` and also by emitting an event from `onDestroy` in MainActivity but it doesn't run the JS.

I believe the bridge between React Native and Native is destroyed at this point so any code triggered in the JS won't run.

Answer (score 0):

You can check AppState Api , it'll tell you about app state like active, background and inactive

Comment: Thanks. I tried it by adding a listener for "change" event. It is not fired when the app is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Without custom modifications I don't think this is possible, you can however try to trigger your react native code in the native handler for when a view gets destroyed... If possible, you should implement a waiting loop there that can be stopped when your react native cleanup is done.

PS: I did not yet try this out myself!